# Counting the number of games played in 1 second using Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know how many games my computer can play in 1000 ms. I did the tests before without using Threads (it plays 13k). Now that I think I'm using threads, I still get the same. Since I don't have much experience with Java threads, I assume I'm doing something wrong but I just can't get it.

Thanks in advance

```
public class SpeedTest<T extends BoardGame> implements Runnable
{
    public static int gamesPlayed = 0;
    private ElapsedTimer timer;
    private double maxTime;
    private BoardAgent<T> agent;
    private BoardGame<T> game;

    public SpeedTest(BoardGame<T> game, ElapsedTimer timer, double maxTime, Random rng)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.timer = timer;
        this.maxTime = maxTime;
        this.agent = new RandomAgent<T>(rng);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            BoardGame<T> newBoard = game.copy();

            while (!newBoard.isGameOver())
                newBoard.makeMove(agent.move(newBoard));

            gamesPlayed++;

            if (timer.elapsedMilliseconds() > maxTime) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        BoardGame<Connect4> game = new Connect4(6, 7);
        double maxTime = 1000;
        ElapsedTimer timer = new ElapsedTimer();
        SpeedTest<Connect4> speedTest1 = new SpeedTest<Connect4>(game, timer, maxTime, rng);
        SpeedTest<Connect4> speedTest2 = new SpeedTest<Connect4>(game, timer, maxTime, rng);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(speedTest1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(speedTest2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) maxTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Games: " + SpeedTest.gamesPlayed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the reason that you are not seeing any speedup is that your application is only using 1 physical processor.  If it is only using one processor, then the two threads won't be running in parallel.  Instead, the processor will be "time-slicing" between the two threads.

What can you do about this?

- Run on a dual-core etc processor.  Or if you have a single processor machine with HT support, enable HT.
- Run the test over a longer time; e.g. a number of minutes.

The reason I suggest the latter is that this could be a JVM warmup effect.  When a JVM starts a new application, it needs to do a lot of class loading and JIT compilation behind the scenes.  These tasks will be largely (if not totally) single-threaded.  Running the tests over a longer period of time reduces the contribution of the "warm up" overheads to the average time per "game".

---

There is a fix that you ought to make to make the program thread-safe.  Change

```
  public static int gamesPlayed = 0;
```

to

```
  private static final AtomicInteger gamesPlayed = new AtomicInteger();
```

and then use `getAndIncrement()` to increment the counter and `intValue()` to fetch its value.  (This is simpler than having each thread maintain its own counter and summing them at the end.)

---

However, I strongly suspect that this change (or @Erik's alternative) will make little difference to the results you are seeing.  I'm now sure it is either:

- JVM warmup issue as described above,
- a consequence of high object creation rates and/or heap starvation, or
- some hidden synchronization issue between the instances of your game.

Comment: I have a Core 2 duo. I ran the simulations for 30 seconds. When I use 2 threads I get 550k games. When I use 1 thread I get 470k. Shouldn't it be almost twice the speed instead?

Comment: @Stephen C: `i++` is not atomic on volatile ints, it's multiple operations.

Comment: @wanstein: Yes it should. What do you get using my approach?

Comment: @Wanstein - not necessarily.  See my second bullet point about JVM warmup.

Comment: @Erik - my mistake.  However, this is highly unlikely to be the cause of @wanstein's "unexpected" lack of apparent speedup.

Comment: @Stephen C: Maybe... 1-2 secs sure, but 30 secs running the same code? His code could execute very quickly and the atomic stuff affect results, he could thrash the cache, he could have some hidden synchronization, hard to say :)

Comment: @Erik - 1) 30 seconds is not enough to be sure IMO.  2) I'll wait and see if using AtomicInteger makes any difference.  3) Another possibility is that his games generate lots of garbage, and what we are seeing is a high (single-threaded) GC overhead.

Comment: @Stephen C: He should run the same test something like 10*30 seconds I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a static int, use a normal member int.

Instead of the sleep, call `.join` on both threads.

Then finally add the member ints.

Comment: It works as well, as long as I give it more time, let's say, 30 seconds instead of one second.

Comment: So I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I thought it was going to be almost twice as fast

Comment: @wanstein: Welcome to the world of threading. You'll need to read up on java synchronization mechanisms, CPU cache and atomic operations first of all :)